# Recover Ubuntu installation after Ext2Fsd installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I have a dual boot setup on my machine. Windows 10 64-Bit and Ubuntu 16.10 64-Bit. This worked until I installed [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=16) in Windows. I can now access my Linux partition from Windows as drive letter but I cannot boot Linux any more.

The error message is `Superblock could not be read, use e2fsck -b 8193 device`.

Any advice on what to do? Running the command from the broken Linux command line did not work.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the output of e2fsck -b 8193 was.

Comment: I guess nobody else is going to write a satisfactory answer which provides more insight soon. Could you please post an answer and mark it as accepted or remove the question? Note that Unix SE has a [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43421/49853).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue using `e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda5` and pressing `a` to automatically correct all errors. Now Ubuntu 16.10 is booting again.

Comment: Do you still use ext2fsd?  Does it still corrupt the superblock?

Comment: I stopped using it.